# Help identifying a manga about a small girl with telekenetic powers

Tags: domu-a-childs-dream

I remember looking through a manga years ago - the book was in Japanese, but I really loved the artwork. I would like to find this book again and see if there is an English version available. The problem is that I haven't been able to find it again and I don't know what it is called.

The book seemed to be about a girl on a bit of a destruction spree with telekinetic powers. Most of the book seems to be set around some flats (tower block) and a playground, which she finally destroys with her powers. I remember there was a man talking to her near the end, possibly trying to capture her. I may be wrong about this, but there may also have been some old people who lived there - I remember an old woman who may have been some relation to the girl.

The original book that I saw had a light blue cover with a picture of the girl on the front with loads of debris behind her. I think it was 80's or early 90's when I first saw the book.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your description reminds me of a manga called [Domu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domu:_A_Child%27s_Dream), which featured a telekinetic girl with other powers as the protagonist.

Most of it took place in an apartment complex, but there were some scenes at a playground just outside the complex

[image]

I believe it was written by the same guy who wrote [Akira](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akira_%28manga%29)

Comment: Yes! Thank you, that's it. I never knew the name, so at least I can search for it now.